# is there a law or a rule to find the multiplication of a sequence n times not the sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

for example how to find $M=(2)(4)(6).....(2n)$.

I found this on a math facebook group:

$U_n=(2n)/(2n+1)$ and $U_n+_1=((2n+1)U_n+2)/(2n+3)$

$P=(1-U_0)(1-U_1)(1-U_2).....(1-U_n)$

-Prove that $P=2^nn!/(2n+1)!$

**What I tried:**

$1-U_n=1/(2n+1)$ so $P=1/[(2(0)+1)][(2(1)+1)].......[(2n+1)]$

so $P=1/[(1)(3)(5).....(n)]$
but I don't know how to continue.

I'm sorry if I didn't write this well, I don't know the formatting rules.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $M$ notice that every factor is divisible by $2$.
So $$M_n = 2 \cdot 4 \cdot \ldots \cdot 2n = (2 \cdot 1) \cdot (2\cdot 2)\cdot \ldots \cdot (2 \cdot n) = 2^n \cdot (1 \cdot 2 \cdot \ldots \cdot n) = 2^n \cdot n!.$$

$P_n$ is $1$ over the product of the first $n+1$ positive odd numbers. So you just have to compute the product
$$1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \dots \cdot (2n+1).$$
But this is just $(2n+1)!$ where you omit the even factors, i.e. the ones contained in $M_n$. So $$\dfrac{1}{P_n} = \dfrac{(2n+1)!}{M_n}.$$

Comment: wow you are awesome, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It's weirdly phrased.  If $n$ is not variable then what is value of $n$ and what are the values of $U_0, U_1,....$ etc for indexes other than $n$?

If $n$ *is* variable and $U_n$ is *defined* to be $U_n = \frac {2n}{2n+1}$ then $U_{n+1}$ would be defined to be $\frac {2(n+1)}{2(n+1) + 1}$ and the claim $U_{n+1} = \frac {(2n+1)U_n + 2}{2n+3}$ is something that needs to be verified.

As $\frac {(2n+1)U_n+2}{2n+3} = \frac {(2n+1)\frac {2n}{2n+1} + 2}{2n+3}= \frac {2n+2}{2n+3}= \frac {2(n+1)}{2(n+1) + 1} = U_{n+1}$, this is verified but  it is not actually the definition.  It's an interesting conjecture but I'm not entirely sure it is needed.  We'll see.....

Now $1 - U_k = 1-\frac {2k}{2k+1} = \frac {2k+1}{2k+1} - \frac {2k}{2k+1}= \frac 1{2k+1}$.

So $P = (1-U_0)(1-U_1)..... (1-U_n) = \frac 11\cdot \frac 1{3} \cdot \frac 15\cdot .... \cdot \frac 1{2n+1} = \frac 1{1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdot ..... \cdot (2n+1)}$

The claim is that that is equal to $\frac {2^n n!}{(2n+1)!}$.  Let's manipulate and try to get that.

$P = \frac 1{1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdot ..... \cdot (2n+1)}$ and the denominator of that is the product of the *odd* integers up to $2n+1$.  To make the denominator equal to $(2n+1)!$ which is the product of *all* integers up to $2n+1$ we must multiply by all the *even* integers up to $2n+1$ (or to $2n$ and $2n+1$ is odd).

So let's do that.  Let's multiply "top and bottom" by the product of all even numbers up to $2n$.

$P = \frac 1{1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdot ..... \cdot (2n+1)}=\frac {2\cdot 4\cdot .....\cdot 2n}{(1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdot ..... \cdot (2n+1))\cdot (2\cdot 4\cdot .....\cdot 2n)}=$

$\frac {2\cdot 4\cdot .....\cdot 2n}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4 \cdot .....\cdot (2n)\cdot (2n+1)}=\frac {2\cdot 4\cdot .....\cdot 2n}{(2n+1)!}$

Now somehow we need to manipulate the numerator which is of the form to $2\cdot 4\cdot ....\cdot 2n$ into $2^n\cdot n!$.  Can we do that?

Well each of the terms is of the form $2k$ and we can factor and put all the factors of $2$ together in one place.  As there are $n$ of these $2$s that will be $2^n$.  And that just leaves the products of $k$ from $1$ to $n$.  And the product of all the $k$s is just $n!$.

So we are done!

$P = (1-U_0)(1-U_1)..... (1-U_n) = \frac 11\cdot \frac 1{3} \cdot \frac 15\cdot .... \cdot \frac 1{2n+1} = \frac 1{1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdot ..... \cdot (2n+1)}=$

$\frac {2\cdot 4\cdot .....\cdot 2n}{(1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdot ..... \cdot (2n+1))\cdot (2\cdot 4\cdot .....\cdot 2n)}=\frac {2\cdot 4\cdot .....\cdot 2n}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4 \cdot .....\cdot (2n)\cdot (2n+1)}=\frac {2\cdot 4\cdot .....\cdot 2n}{(2n+1)!}=$

$\frac {(2\cdot 1)\cdot (2\cdot 2) \cdot ......\cdot (2\cdot n)}{(2n+1)!}=$

$\frac {\underbrace{2\cdot 2\cdot.....\cdot 2}_{n\text{ times}}\cdot(1\cdot 2\cdot .... \cdot n)}{(2n+1)!}=$

$\frac {2^nn!}{(2n+1)!}$.

.....

Alternatively we could have worked the other way:

$\frac {2^nn!}{(2n+1)!} = $

$\frac {(2\cdot 1)(2\cdot 2).....(2\cdot n)}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5 ....\cdot (2n)\cdot (2n+1)}=$

$\frac { 2\cdot 4\cdot ...\cdot 2n}{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5 ....\cdot (2n)\cdot (2n+1)}=$

$\frac {1}{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot ...\cdot (2n+1)}=$

$\frac 11\cdot \frac 13\cdot \frac 15\cdot ....\cdot \frac1{2n+1}=$

$(1-\frac 01)(1-\frac 23)(1-\frac 45)...(1-\frac {2n}{2n+1})=$

$(1-U_0)(1-U_1)(1-U_2)......(1-U_n)=P$.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and for writing this, I understand now